# Ruby GPGME::Error> Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, gpgme

I'm unable to import a key file. I'm using ruby 1.9.3 and ruby-gpgme
https://github.com/ueno/ruby-gpgme

```
require "gpgme"

begin
  key = GPGME::Key.import(File.open("private.key"), {:password => "redacted"})

rescue GPGME::Error => g
  puts g.inspect
  puts g.message
  puts g.code
  puts g.source
end
```

Output

Inappropriate ioctl for device

More info: 
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gpgme-2.0.2/lib/gpgme/ctx.rb:43:in `new': Inappropriate ioctl for device (GPGME::Error)
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gpgme-2.0.2/lib/gpgme/key.rb:120:in`import'
    from gpgme.rb:17:in `'

Here is the ctx.rb file, but I don't get what could be causing the issue...
https://github.com/ueno/ruby-gpgme/blob/master/lib/gpgme/ctx.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was a result of some issue with gpgme.  So I reinstalled gpgme.  I used "brew gpgme".  now it seems to be working.